# UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: Loaded ObjectBox core dynamic library has unsupported version 0.18.1, expected ^0.19.0)

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I get this exception at the startup of the app.
`UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: Loaded ObjectBox core dynamic library has unsupported version 0.18.1, expected ^0.19.0)`

```
Flutter 3.15.0-15.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 0d074ced6c (3 hours ago) • 2023-09-21 10:24:15 -0700
Engine • revision 453411bcf3
Tools • Dart 3.2.0 (build 3.2.0-134.1.beta) • DevTools 2.27.0
```

```
sdk: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'

objectbox: ^2.1.0
objectbox_flutter_libs: ^2.1.0
objectbox_generator: ^2.1.0
```

I tried it on Windows and Linux and tried the following script like they say in their docs.

`bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/main/install.sh)`
In windows I copied the files to System32 and in Linux it installs the .so file globally but it does not work on either platform.

Edit: Same problem with the objectbox example projects.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade the Pub Cache Dart version of object box to 2.0.0 it will works

Answer (score 1):

2.3.0 does not work with Android.

Downgrading to 2.2.0 solved the problem.

objectbox: 2.2.0 (whithout the ^)

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/563)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed with [release 2.3.1](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/releases/tag/v2.3.1). Run `flutter pub upgrade` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The updated Android Objecybox library should fix this problem.

You can find this issue and solution on GitHub

https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/499#issuecomment-1376840360

\android\app\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // Add objectbox-android-objectbrowser only for debug builds.
    // Warning: when objectbox_flutter_libs updates check if version
    // needs update, e.g. check https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/releases.
   def objectboxVersion = "3.7.0"
    debugImplementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-android-objectbrowser:$objectboxVersion")
    releaseImplementation("io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion")

}
```